# Getting previous pointer using data c++ linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have the following code, and im trying to write the fix for the following scenario: that the number passed in the parameter does not exist in the list, therefore it does not have a previous

this function should: *accepts a value
which it will use to traverse the list and the first node it finds whose data is the
same, it will return a pointer to the ListNode before the matching node.*

```
  //return a pointer to the ListNode before the matching node data
template < typename NODETYPE >
  ListNode < NODETYPE > * List < NODETYPE >::prevPointerUsingData(NODETYPE &data) {
    ListNode < NODETYPE > *previousPtr = NULL;
    ListNode < NODETYPE > *currentPtr = firstPtr;

    //first node cannot have a previous
    if(data == currentPtr->data) {
        cout << "canot have a previous node" << endl;
        return 0;
    }else {
        //traverse until you've met the previous' node's data
        while (currentPtr->nextPtr != NULL) {
            if(currentPtr->nextPtr->data == data){
                //previous is assigned the current node
                previousPtr = currentPtr;
                currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
                cout << previousPtr->data << " <--previousData" << endl;
                return previousPtr;
            }else {
                currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
            }
        }if(currentPtr->nextPtr == NULL && currentPtr->nextPtr->data != data) {
            cout << "no such node" << endl;
            return 0;
        }


    }


}
```

If i enter a number(data) like anything that's not in my list, it crashes. Is there logic wrong somewhere?

**EDIT:**
I wrote this code that works, although im thinking of adding the `IF` check to see if list is empty, if it is return 0. I was taking this code and applying it to the one above, simply because it does the same thing, except the one above uses the data from the node, and the below uses the pointer.

this function should: *accept an int specifying the
location of a node within the list and will return a pointer to the ListNode before that node.*

```
//return pointer to the ListNode before that node
template < typename NODETYPE >
  ListNode < NODETYPE > * List < NODETYPE > ::prevPointerUsingPosition(int position) {
    ListNode < NODETYPE > * previousPtr = NULL;
    ListNode < NODETYPE > * currentPtr = firstPtr;

    if(position < 1) {
        return 0;
    }else if( position > sizeOfList()) {
        return 0;
    }else {
        for(int i = 1; i < position-1; i++) {
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }
        previousPtr = currentPtr;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        cout << previousPtr->data << " <--previousData" << endl;
        return previousPtr;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: On which line does it crash? What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: You have two glaring redundancies in your code. One is the `else`, which is not needed because the previous block ends in `return`. The other is the test for `currentPtr->nextPtr == NULL` in the `if` -- you already know it is since that's the only condition under which the previous `while` loop would end. These redundancies make the code harder to understand.

Comment: Best way to figure out Linked lists is to visualize them. Draw the list out with pen and paper or your drawing tool of choice. Draw your way through all the changes that are needed to insert, remove, and any other functionality you require. Base your code on the drawings.

Comment: I did the change that Saurav Sahu mentioned, and it does not crash anymore, the cout statement i have in that IF conditional does not print, but it returns 0... Why is that?

Comment: Check individually, at the very beginning, if `firstPtr` is null or not, if it is `null`, `cout` before returning.

Comment: I have a function isEmpty() that has in it `return firstPtr` == 0; now, what you're saying is equivalent to saying ` if(isEmpty()) { cout << whatever; return 0;}` right?

Answer (score 3):

you have done a mistake in below statement,

```
  if(currentPtr->nextPtr == NULL && currentPtr->nextPtr->data != data)
```

If `currentPtr->nextPtr` is `NULL` then you are dereferencing this null pointer in`currentPtr->nextPtr->data != data` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(currentPtr->nextPtr == NULL && currentPtr->nextPtr->data != data)
```

to

```
if(currentPtr->nextPtr != NULL && currentPtr->nextPtr->data != data)
```

Plus, you should check `firstPtr` for non-null before dereferencing it in first `if` statement.

Comment: I've created another function called prevPointerUsingPosition and it works, i was just trying to apply the same concept, but it didn't work fully. I'll edit code above for it